# Insert data to multiple tables

Tags: c#, sql-server

I need help with inserting data to multiple tables. I have 3 tables:

- `Revizija` (rev_id, Broj_rev)
- `Verzija` (verz_id, Broj_verz, rev_id)
- `Program` (prog_id, Naziv_prog, verz_id)

Connected with FK - `revizija` to `verzija`, `verzija` to `programski` sustav.

My insert fails when I try to run program.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database1"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand("Insert into Revizija Values(@Broj_rev)", con);
xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Broj_rev", textBox5.Text);

con.Open();
xp.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();

SqlCommand xp1 = new SqlCommand("Insert into Verzija values(@Broj)", con);
xp1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Broj", textBox4.Text);

con.Open();
xp1.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();

SqlCommand xp4 = new SqlCommand("Insert into Program values (@Naziv_prog)", con);
xp4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Naziv_prog", textBox2.Text);

con.Open();
xp4.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Are rev_id, verz_id and prog_id IDENTITY columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to insert data in the `Verzija` table you need to know the value assigned to the primary key of the `Revizija` table and the same happens when you try to insert a record in the `Program` table with the `Revizija`.

In this scenario you could use the ability of SQL Server to execute two commands together and add to each of your first two commands the sql `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY`() command text. The SCOPE_IDENTITY returns the value of the last IDENTITY value assigned through your connection. The result of that command can be read using ExecuteScalar and used as an input parameter for the following command.

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(....))
using(SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand(@"Insert into Revizija 
                                       (Broj_rev) Values(@Broj_rev);
                                       SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()", con);
{
    con.Open();
    xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Broj_rev", textBox5.Text);
    int rev_id Convert.ToInt32(xp.ExecuteScalar());

    using(SqlCommand xp1 = new SqlCommand(@"Insert into Verzija 
                    (Broj_verz, rev_id) values(@Broj,@rev_id);
                    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()", con);
    {
        xp1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Broj", textBox4.Text);
        xp1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rev_id", rev_id);
        int verz_id = Convert.ToInt32(xp1.ExecuteScalar());

        using(SqlCommand xp4 = new SqlCommand(@"Insert into Program 
                (Naziv_prog, verz_id) values (@Naziv_prog, @verz_id)", con);
        {
            xp4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Naziv_prog", textBox2.Text);
            xp4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@verz_id", verz_id);
            xp4.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Notice also that I have fixed the main error in your queries. In an INSERT INTO statement, if you omit the column names, then you are required to provide values for all fields present (otherwise the engine is not able to correctly assign your passed values to the matching columns) For clarity and to avoid future errors always specify the columns  that will be updated by the query

Comment: i am getting An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe error on sqlconnection line.

Comment: Well, I have not written all the _ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database1"].ConnectionString_ but of course you should have that instead of ... And in case you have already done it then check if your app.config contains a section for ConnectionStrings with one entry named Database1

Comment: It has two entries.

Comment: If the NRE happens on the creation of the connection and you have the correct call to ConfigurationManager in place then the only possibility is a missing key for "Database1", I am sorry, but it is time for me to go to work, my shift starts and I need to leave the site. Goodnight

Comment: Tnx for the help.

Comment: Steve thank you very much for your help. It works now.